# Setting up HTTPS on Tomcat 6

Tags: ssl, https, tomcat6

I am trying to configure tomcat 6 with SSL. I am running windows XP. I tried to follow the steps at (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

However, I don't have any files called keytool in the %tomcat home%\bin folder, which is referred in the site. Do I need to download it separately? Where can I find one for windows and Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keytool.exe` is included in the `Java SDK distribution` at least with the SUN distribution.

```
<Path to Java SDK>\bin
```

The documentation which you refer to is also stating `%JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: I may feel silly now. That's because of me. Thanks fyr. It works now :-)